# Timepicker (trentrichardson) - how to trigger hour dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using trentrichardson's jQuery timepicker (https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon)

If a user clicks on a relevant time input field, currently the timepicker module will pop up. I'd like the hour dropdown ('select' input) within this module to automatically be activated, i.e. so that the user only has to click once on the time input field to see the hour options, rather than having to click twice: once on the time input field, then once on the hour select input.

I have multiple time input fields on the page if that's relevant

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is the drop-down a real `select` element, or is it emulated using some other elements?

Comment: @teemu It's a real select element; I'm not sure the best way to 'choose' the right one via jQuery selectors $() though since as I said there are lots of time input fields on the page